# Dimension of nullspace and number of rows

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-rank

> A matrix $A$ has $10$ columns and dim(Null($A^{T}$ ))$=7$. The smallest possible number of rows of $A$ is
>
> $(A)$ $5$
>
> $(B)$ $6$
>
> $(C)$ $7$
>
> $(D)$ $8$
>
> $(E)$ $9$

I know that dim(Null($A^{T}$ ))$=7$ implies that there are $7$ rows of zeros and that:

Rank($A$)+Nullity($A^T$) $=$ # of rows

Rank($A$)+Nullity($A$) $=$ # of columns

I'm not really sure how to use all this information though... Can someone provide a hint?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: You want Rank($A$)+Nullity($A^T$) to be as low as possible. You already know how large the right term is. What's the lowest possible the left term could theoretically be? What would the resulting matrix be?

Comment: How do I know how large the right side is though? I only know that there are 10 columns but how do I know the largest possible number of rows? Just because I have 7 rows of zeroes does not mean that the largest number of rows I have is 7.

Comment: The problem says, right out, that the nullity is $7$. That's the right term. You want the whole expression to be as low as possible, which means you want the remaining left term (the rank) to be as low as possible. What's the lowest possible rank a matrix can have, and what do you know about matrices with that rank?

Comment: Ohh I see. By right term, you meant the Nullity($A^T$) not the number of rows... I thought by right side, you meant the number of columns.

Comment: I didn't mean the right side of the equation you wrote. I meant the right side of the expression I wrote, yes.

Comment: In that case, I guess to make this as small as possible rank would be $0$ which implies that we have $7$ free variables spanning a $7$ dimensional vector space so the smallest number of rows would be $7$?

Comment: The smallest possible rank is $0$, and such a matrix has only entries which are $0$. Is there a matrix with only zeroes which fulfills the criteria of your problem?

Comment: Couldn't I just use a $7 \times 7$ $0$ matrix then?

Comment: That wouldn't be 10 columns. But otherwise, yes.

Comment: Oops. Yes. $7 \times 10$. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

$A$ has $10$ columns implies you can view $A$ as a linear map $A:\Bbb R^{10} \to \Bbb R^m$ and $A^T$ as a linear map $A^T:\Bbb R^{m} \to \Bbb R^{10}$ where the $m$ we do not know. Here $\dim (\text{Null}( A^T))=7$ implies $7 \leq m$  and $\text{rank}(A^T) \le 10$. Also $\text{rank}(A^T)=\text{rank}(A) \leq m$. so $7 \leq m \leq 10$